# App Crashes when click back button in android

Tags: java, android

I am using an activity in multiple screens, and the app crashes when I click back button on a specific one screen only, but it works fine on the others...

So I call the screen in the below method:

```
@Override
public void donateOnClic(ActivityOrganizationModel activityOrganizationModel) {
    DonateActivity.startActivity(activityOrganizationModel, getScreenName(), getContext());
    try {
        sendToMixpanelLanguage(Config.MIXPANEL_EVENT_DONATION_ACTIVITY);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is the below exception I found when I click back button:

```
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
E/HTTP: <-- 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR https://automator.appgain.io/automessages/5e403f53970b2b000b92de74/firevent/userdidnotdonate/123468393 (7568ms)
E/HTTP: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-parse-master-key,x-parse-application-id,Accept,Accept-Version,Content-Length,Content-MD5,Content-Type,Date,X-Auth-Token,authToken,appapikey,Authorization,appid
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Date: Sun, 07 Nov 2021 09:00:58 GMT
    Server: gunicorn/19.6.0
    Via: kong/0.11.2
    X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 2862
    X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 3764
    Content-Length: 291
    Connection: keep-alive
E/HTTP: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
    <-- END HTTP (291-byte body)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.quantatil.ikhar, PID: 22387
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
        at io.appgain.sdk.controller.Utils.getAppGainFailure(Utils.java:81)
        at io.appgain.sdk.controller.Automator$1$2.onResponse(Automator.java:65)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813) 
        at io.appgain.sdk.controller.Utils.getAppGainFailure(Utils.java:81) 
        at io.appgain.sdk.controller.Automator$1$2.onResponse(Automator.java:65) 
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: What does _sendToMixpanelLanguage()_ do?

Comment: @GokulNathKP I didn't cause any problem it's just adding log events to mixpanel 
https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004596186-Which-common-mobile-events-can-Mixpanel-collect-on-my-behalf-automatically-

Comment: which line of your code is causing the issue? did you paste the code?

Comment: @SauravKumar the problem that's the logcat does not shows the line that cause the problem... but it seems when I click back and close the popup window or activity and go back to the previous fragment it crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

This happens when you try to convert an `Json` object to `POJO` but in this case the `Json` object & `POJO` object doesn't match at all, so `Gson` throw this `Exception`

```
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

So, the application is crashing on `Gson` conversation state where `Gson`  was expacting an `Json` object (respective to your `POJO`) but got an `HTML` page.

Comment: So the problem from the server not from my side right?

Comment: There can be problem with your `API` request, so that's why server return `500` but you should also manage from your end according to `HTTP Status`. Now, server return `500` so you shouldn't do the `GSON` conversation and handle the error on your end.

Comment: so do you any idea to implement and solve this issue, or there's any docs related to this issue :)?

Comment: Read `Retrofit` documentation to more about it.

Comment: it seems that the problem as you said from the internal server, but any way thanks let me try to solve this :)

Comment: I found the problem is from our server that's the problem is from the triggerPointName doesn't exists in the server side, it solved finally :)